# Using DECODE in PL/SQL procedure call

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a stored PL/SQL procedure (say X) that inserts records into a table. I am calling that procedure from another procedure (say Y). I have some parameters in procedure Y like para1,para2,para3 which can have two values either zero or one, for zero and one values I have one id stored in a TBL_SETUP, and when I call procedure X I want to check that if para1 is null then return null, if it is not null then check if it is one then return YES_ID and if it is no then return NO_ID.

I have tried something like this. I wrote a SELECT statement for getting YES_ID,NO_ID before calling the procedure and it is working fine, but when I write procedure call as below, it is giving me error "PLS-00204: Function or pseudo-column may be used inside a SQL statement only". How to use `DECODE` in a procedure call?

```
PROC_X(DECODE(para1,NULL,NULL,DECODE(para1,'1',YES_ID,NO_ID)),para2,NULL,NULL,DECODE(para2,'1',YES_ID,NO_ID)),para3,NULL,NULL,DECODE(para3,'1',YES_ID,NO_ID)),)
```

Comment: `decode` is one of those functions that only exists in SQL and not in PL/SQL.

Comment: Your example procedure call has mismatched brackets and ends with `,)`, otherwise I would convert it to the equivalent `CASE` expression.

Comment: `CASE` statement would be appropriate as it is verbose than `DECODE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `SELECT INTO`:

```
DECLARE 
   DECODE_RESULT VARCHAR2(100); -- or any suitable data type
BEGIN
   SELECT DECODE(...) INTO DECODE_RESULT FROM dual;

   PROC_X(DECODE_RESULT);

END;
```